# reading a json in spark missing json datasource

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a sample json file into the SqlContext using the below code, but it fails with the datasource error followed.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val path = "C:\\samplepath\\sample.json"
val jsondata = sqlContext.read.json(path)
```

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: json.
>   Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: json.DefaultSource
>           at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:83)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
>           at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
>           at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:82)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
>           ... 50 more

I tried to look for a spark package that might be missing, but couldn't find anything helpful to fix it.

I tried a similar code using Pyspark, but it failed with a similar json datasource ClassNotFoundException.

Upon further trying to convert an existing RDD to JsonRDD, I was able to get the results successfully. Is there something I am missing ? I am using Spark-1.6.1 on Scala-2.10.5. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
val stringRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(""" 
  { "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$1,431.73",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "blue"
  }""",
   """{
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,515.60",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 34,
    "eyeColor": "blue"
  }""", 
  """{
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,765.29",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 26,
    "eyeColor": "blue"
  }""")
)
sqlContext.jsonRDD(stringRDD).registerTempTable("testjson")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT age from testjson").collect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created the jar using the source code, and hence I believe the issue was with some missing resources. I downloaded the latest jar from the spark website & it worked as expected.